# What happens when utensils are washed in detergent or soap.what type of reaction it is?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

What happens when plates after dinner are washed with soap or detergent ? What colour change is observed? What type of reaction it is?

Comment: The only color change I can think of is the dishes becoming cleaner

Answer (score 2):

Broadly speaking, what you have is not a chemical reaction (no bonds are created and destroyed) but *supra*molecular processes (so molecules rearrange and interact differently with each other, without changing their formula). The main process when cleaning with soap is the formation of emulsions. Soap molecules typically have a polar head (which has affinity for water) and an apolar tail (which loves the fatty leftovers in your plate). The fatty residues won't dissolve in water, but the soap molecules will coat small droplets of fat with the apolar tails touching the fat (which is good) and the polar heads touching the water (which is also good). These droplets covered in soap are called "micelles", and they can be very stable (if you had the same fat without soap they wouln't be, and the fat and the water would separate, as happens with water and oil). This actually gets very complicated and there are many many details to it, but that's the basics.

Surfactants (the technical term for soap-like molecules) are also involved in the foams, aerosols, dispersions, wetting and many other supramolecular phenomena involving more than one phase (such as water/air, water/oil...).

Answer (score -1):

There's no such thing like color change that I have observed but as far as the mechanism I can say it has to do with hydrophilic and hydrophobic parts of long chain carboxylic acid(soap)and long chain sulphonates of carbon (detergents) you can take reference from web for further research.